# Adding additional fields on top of an inherited model and expose all super and child class fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, database-design, associations, single-table-inheritance

**My Goal:**

I'm trying to create two different types of users, with different profiles.

`Barber`, `Client`, `BarberProfile`, and `ClientProfile`

I have my base `User` object that contains information like `email`, `password`, and all the other fields that Devise keeps track of.

I'd like the base `User` model to have one `Profile` that keeps track of all basic information that I want all my users to have. For instance, `first_name`, `last_name`, `avatar`, etc.

I'm using single table inheritance to create two different types of users: `Client` and `Barber`.

I want each of these types of users to have a base `Profile` associated with it, and then have additional fields that belong to a `BarberProfile` and a `ClientProfile`, respectively.

The `BarberProfile` will have things that the `Barber` needs, but the `Client` doesn't. For instance, a `bio`. The `ClientProfile` will have things the `Client` needs, but the `Barber` doesn't. For instance, `hair_type`.

**What I currently have, and my problem:**

As stated above, I've created a table for `User` and `Profile`. So I'm able to call `user.profile.first_name`. I created a `BarberProfile` and `ClientProfile` table in order to add the extra fields.

I'd like to just be able to reference `user.profile.bio` if the user type is `Barber`. But `bio` isn't a part of the base profile. So in this case I'd have to create an associated `Profile` *and* and associated `BarberProfile` to get everything I need. I could just do `user.profile.first_name` and `user.barber_profile.bio`, but it feels messy, and I'm making two different associations from essentially the same type of model. I feel like it should be a simple thing to just have the `BarberProfile` inherit all fields from `Profile` and add its own specific `Barber` fields on top.

How does one go about doing this in Rails?

**Edit:** One of the main reasons I want to do this is so I can update things like `first_name` and `bio` within the same form for a `Barber`. And similarly, a `first_name` and `hair_type` within the same form for a `Client`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using two associations on the users for Profile and Client/BarberProfile, I think you should make ClientProfile and BarberProfile extend Profile (single table inheritance) and each of them "has one :barber_profile_data" (I'm not sure how to call it). To fix the long method calls, you can use delegated methods.

```
class Barber > User
  has_one :barber_profile
  delegate :bio, to: :barber_profile

class Client < User
  has_one :client_profile
  delegate :first_name, to: :client_profile

class BarberProfile < Profile
  has_one :barber_profile_data
  delegate :bio, to: :barber_profile_data

class ClientProfile < Profile
  has_one :client_profile_data
  delegate :first_name, to: :client_profile_data
```

Then, when you do "@barber.bio", it should call, internally, "@barber.barber_profile.barber_profile_data.bio".

Comment: Thanks for the input. I like the idea, as extending profile was my first instinct and seems pretty intuitive. So in your suggestion, barber_profile_data exists as a separate table? Is it possible to update bio from one form with this setup?

Comment: Yes, BarberProfileData should have its own table. About the update, it should be possible, check rails form_for method fields_for and play with that. Anyway, you can always customize the update action and do wahatever you need to set the right fields_for.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good use case for [Multiple Table Inheritance](http://www.belighted.com/blog/implementing-multiple-table-inheritance-in-rails). In MTI you use additional tables to decorate the base model.

The main advantage to MTI is that the `clients` and `barbers` tables can contain the specific columns for that type vs STI which requires you to cram everything into `users` by design (thats why they call it single table).

```
create_table "barbers", force: :cascade do |t|
  # only the specific attributes
  t.text     "bio"
end

create_table "clients", force: :cascade do |t|
  # only the specific attributes
  t.string   "hair_type"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
  # ... all the other common attributes
  t.integer  "actable_id"
  t.string   "actable_type"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
end
```

This is an example with the [ActiveRecord::ActsAs](https://github.com/krautcomputing/active_record-acts_as) gem.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  actable
end

class Barber < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as :user
end

class Client < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as :user
end
```

Note that `Barber` and `Client` should not be true subclasses. `ActiveRecord::ActsAs` instead delegates to the "actable" class.

You can then do `Barber.all` or `Client.all` to fetch specific types or use `User.all.map(:specific)` to get decorated users of all types.